# AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior stop and restart using buttons

Tags: ajax, timer, wicket

```
timer= new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(4)) {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) {


            List<Animal> newData = animalDaoImpl.getByCriteriaAndIdsAbove(
                    animal, lastId);

            if (newData != null & newData.size() > 0) {
                animals.getObject().addAll(newData);
            }

            target.add(animalWmc);
            this.stop(target);              
        }
    };
    add(timer);


add(new AjaxLink<String>("start") {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        timer.restart(target);  
        }
    });
```

Hi everyone.

above i have code that sets up a timer and stops it before it has a chance to start.

I then have a link which on click should restart the timer and then the timer should do it's thing.

However on click of the button the timer hits the database twice then stops for no reason. Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening. Thanks

Comment: I don't see the your code to set up the timer and stop it immediately. From what I understand, this can't be done. You set Duration.seconds(4), so it's more likely, that you click the AjaxLink at the same time as your timer triggers. It stops because you have "this.stop(target);" in "onTimer" - thats the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple solution (but sure not the best one):

Execute the code in `onTimer` depending on a boolean variable

```
    @Override
    protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        if (executeTimer) {
            // do your database stuff, ...
            target.add(animalWmc);
        }
    }
```

and change the value for `executeTimer` in `onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target)`

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        executeTimer = true;
    }
```